# stop animation on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

My mouseover function animates the width of an object but when it reaches its destination it moves back and forth 2 or 3 pixles. Is there a solution to this problem.

```
$(this).mousover(function() {
    $('myselector').animate( {'width': 200} ); 
    // this is all have for my animation but it moves alot
});
```

Comment: Could you please create a test case for this on [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I created my own [test](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/3rZAP/), and I can't reproduce what you are describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to animate width to 200 px on `mouseover` and then to animate it back (ex: to 100 px) on `mouseout` this can help:

```
$(this).mouseover(function() {
        $('myselector').stop().animate( {'width': 200} ); 
       });

$(this).mouseout(function() {
            $('myselector').stop().animate( {'width': 100} ); 
           });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: This isn't really related to his question. Yes, this stops an animation, but it doesn't fix littleMan's "2 or 3 pixles" :)

Answer (score 0):

Often times stop() alone won't do the trick, you'll need to pass "true", parameters to also clear the document animation queue:

```
.stop('true', 'true);
```

Full documentation here:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/stop-true-true-animation-chains-and-callbacks